# UIButton partly not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, autolayout

I have a UIButton in a UITableViewCell that segues to another view controller. Nothing fancy. Problem is, only the right half of the respond, and that is only in the first cell. Button works perfectly on cell number 2, 3, […], 10 000. Only the first cell has this problem, and for half the width of the button.

I am using autolayout. I set the width, the height, the leading space and the top space to superview, so this should not be the issue (but I might be mistaken!).

There is no code to show since this has all been done in Interface Builder. Here are the settings of my UIButton:

[image]

Comment: Either your UIButton is placed outside the bounds of its superview, or another view is blocking the touches.

Comment: None are the case on my code. the button is set directly in the content view, and everything is set with layout constraints.

Comment: To prove my point furthermore, I reaffirm that only the first cell behaves this way. The second cell and more are fine.

Comment: The only other things I can think of are gesture recognizers, or overriding the `hitTest:` method to alter the responder chain. Are you doing either of these?  If not, can you provide a minimal sample project that reproduces the issue?

Comment: It's not even the case. Is there a way I can print the view hierarchy or override hitTest: to ensure my button is there waiting to be pushed?

Comment: You can type `po [self.view recursiveDescription]` in the debugger.  You could also override hitTest, just call the super implementation and set a breakpoint in there, and see what it returns.